# Io of NMOS in small signal analysis

Tags: nmos

The question is almost 7 years old and a few people seemed to be interested in this question. But the person who had posted the question said it's from textbook. I have doubt whether \$I_o\$ it's correct.

[image: circuit schematics]

The guy said
$$I_o = g_m V_{gs}$$

However, I think
$$I_o = g_m V_{gs}  - I_{gd}$$
$$I_o = g_m V_{gs}  - s V_{gs} C_{gd}$$

Original link to the question [orginal question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259231/nmos-small-signal-high-frequency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feZurU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\text{I}_0+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_0+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}&=\text{I}_0+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_0+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_3
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

And solve for \$\text{I}_0\$:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_0+\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_\text{i}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{I}_0=\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}-\text{n}\right)\tag4$$

Now, we can transform the transfer function using [Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). This gives \$\displaystyle\text{R}_1=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}\$ and \$\displaystyle\text{R}_2=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2}\$. So, we get:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{i}_0&=\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\left(\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}-\text{n}\right)\\
\\
&=\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\left(\text{sC}_2-\text{n}\right)
\end{alignat*}
\tag5
$$

**EDIT,** when transforming back to the time-domain we can use the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the Laplace Tranform:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0\left(t\right)&=\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{sC}_2-\text{n}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\left(\text{C}_2\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{s}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}-\text{n}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[1\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\left(\text{C}_2\cdot\delta'\left(t-\tau\right)-\text{n}\cdot\delta\left(t-\tau\right)\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\text{C}_2\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\delta'\left(t-\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau-\text{n}\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\delta\left(t-\tau\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\text{C}_2\left(\text{V}_\text{i}\left(0\right)\delta\left(t\right)-\text{V}_\text{i}'\left(t\right)\left(2\theta\left(t\right)-1\right)\right)-\text{n}\text{V}_\text{i}\left(t\right)\left(2\theta\left(t\right)-1\right)
\end{alignat*}
\tag6
$$

Comment: Why do you assume the current Io it's from left to right  ->?

Comment: @kile I didn't choose that specifically, just choose a direction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct.

The final expression must be:
$$
I_o = V_{gs}(g_m-sC_{gd})
$$

The first expression was probably derived assuming a low-frequency small-signal model, i.e. parasitic capacitors are not there.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know I am correct.